# Lightning components - Having problems using format on a ui:inputnumber

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a component attribute that is a double. I'm putting it in a ui:inputNumber that can have a user input or be set from a calculation. I'd like for it to be displayed to 2 decimal places. On init it displays to two places put after a component.set if the number has more decimal places they're displayed. For the ui:inputNumber's format attribute I've tried .00 , #.00 , #.00#.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the format to `#,##0.##` or `0.##` should work.

```
<ui:outputNumber format="#,##0.##"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, neither of those worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `lightning:formattedNumber` for formatting the number as per your desire.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_formattedNumber.htm

Comment: lightning:formattedNumber is not an input field

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to reproduce your problem, for me it always worked with `format=".00"`. I tried to change the referenced attribute and the value directly, both worked fine:

[image]

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="num" type="integer" default="10"/>
    <ui:inputNumber aura:id="inputField" label="Number" format=".00" value="{!v.num}"/>
    <lightning:button label="Change Value" onclick="{!c.changeValue}" />
    <lightning:button label="Change Attribute" onclick="{!c.changeAttribute}" />
</aura:application>
```

Controller:

```
({
    changeValue: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        cmp.set("v.num", 10.123);
    },

    changeAttribute: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        cmp.find("inputField").set("v.value", 10.123);
    },
})
```

What is different in your case?

Answer (score -3):

You can use **lightning:formattedNumber** which has attribute *maximumFractionDigits* using which you can set the decimal places.

More info can be found [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_formattedNumber.htm)

Comment: lightning:formattedNumber is not an input field